# Condition not executed properly when using getchar()

Tags: c, getchar

When I use getchar in this code, the output doesn't run correctly and consecutively!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, sum=0, num;
    float ave;
    const int n = 5;
    clrscr();

    for(i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("Enter number %d: ", i+1);
        num = getchar();
        sum += num;
    }

    ave = (float) sum / n;
    printf("\nThe average is: %6.2f", ave);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

```
Output:

Enter number 1: 1
Enter number 2: Enter number 3: 2
Enter number 4: Enter number 5: 3
The average is: 34.00
```

Comment: [Clarification needed regarding getchar() and newline](//stackoverflow.com/a/12544121)

Comment: Also, note that `getchar()` will return the char code of the digit. You need to convert to a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getchar` is a buffered function that holds the newline in the buffer. Correct code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, sum=0, num;
    float ave;
    const int n = 5;
    for(i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("Enter number %d: ", i+1);
        num = getchar();
        getchar(); // Eat the buffered input
        sum += num;
    }
    ave = (float) sum / n;
    printf("\nThe average is: %6.2f", ave);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

(I don't have Windows and `conio.h`), but it should be the same. The extra call to `getchar` is for 'eating' the buffered newline.